# Should I ignore this disk error?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

So I recently took a 500GB HDD which already had error with catalog-B tree from a dead MacBook to recover from files, So after recovering the data I formatted the disk and started it using it for backup purposes and I wanted to repair the disk and check for any problems and I did get a problem when I ran first-aid on the parent Disk:
[image]

And I ran a terminal command to fix it the problem but it failed:

```
bash-$ diskutil repairDisk disk
Repairing the partition map might erase disks, proceed? (yN) y
Started partition map repair on disk                                            
Checking prerequisites                                           
Checking the partition list
Adjusting partition map to fit whole disk as required
Checking for an EFI system partition    
Checking the EFI system partition's size    
Checking the EFI system partition's file system
Checking the EFI system partition's folder content        
Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map
456789   
Error: -69854: A disk with a mount point is required
bash-$ exit
exit
```

But if I format the parent disk as Apple Partiton Map or master boot record it does not show any error while repairing the parent Disk. So should I worry or should I do something about it?
Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Thanks for all your answers but I don't know how but the problem has fixed itself:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the Terminal output, you used `diskutil repairDisk disk` as the _command_ and that is malformed. In the man page for `diskutil` it shows `repairDisk device` and `disk` is not a valid _device parameter_. It's lacking its id, e.g. `disk2` and I'd assume that's why it erred out.

Answer (score 2):

You should never ignore disk errors. Assume it's dying; make backups, you can never have too many. I use time machine and carbon copy cloner, but do what suits you. I also use disk warrior sometimes to buy some time if I think a disk is going. But don't kid yourself, that drive is probably not healthy and it wouldn't be good to fool yourself into thinking everything will be fine. It may be, but it also may not be; if you have important files, act accordingly, and while hoping for the best, plan for the worst.